# What is comanswer.com and why is it copying stackoverflow.com content?

Tags: discussion, seo, copycat-sites

I just did a search for "find out how much memory a python program takes" on Google and came up with two hits that contain the same content:

- [www.comanswer.com/question/python-script-knows-how-much-memory-it-s-using](http://web.archive.org/web/20101226085054/http://www.comanswer.com/question/python-script-knows-how-much-memory-it-s-using)
- [Python script knows how much memory it's using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240581/python-script-knows-how-much-memory-its-using)

Interestingly, the `comanswer.com` site was higher ranked. I guess they do a better job at search engine optimization (SEO).

Answer (score 5):

It is yet another site that scrapes Stack Overflow. However, you will find a link stating that the question originated from SO. Also, each username links back to his or her appropriate user page on SO.

Based on their attribution to SO, it appears to be fulfilling the requirements under cc-wiki. For more information: [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/), [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). See the footer at the bottom of all Stack Exchange pages.

Comment: It's too bad that there isn't some sort of restriction for sites that just want to copy content en-masse.  There are licenses for some software that states that, if you use a particular library, you cannot redistribute it as a mere copy of itself, that you have to actually add some value.  I'm not sure that scattering StackOverflow content all over the internet in this way really helps the world.

Comment: @robert ironically, if it is *properly attributed* and results in better matches (I'm not saying it should, but if it does) then it does actually meet our goal of getting information to the world. Currently what we have is largely a Google failing -- with the exception of the "primary tag in title" thing, which was our mistake and is now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

There's no copyright infringement here.  All stackoverflow content has a creative commons license.  There are a few strings attached, but this site seems to meet all the requirements.  As for ranking higher than stack overflow itself... well, they're [working](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title) [on](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1985264) [that](http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/12721357573857280).

Comment: I've gotten in the practice of directing my searches in FF. Depending on what I'm searching, I direct to SO, MSDN, etc. I would be interested to know if these directed searches do anything to improve visibility in general searches.

Answer (score 0):

The website infringed copyright [as of your posting](http://web.archive.org/web/20101226085054/http://www.comanswer.com/question/python-script-knows-how-much-memory-it-s-using), although not in the worst way, because the footer was literally

> The questions and answers come from stackoverflow.com, serverfault.com and superuser.com, and are licensed under the cc-wiki license. Logo, design and layout © 2010 ComAnswer.com SimpleAnswer

The link back to the original questions and authors are not enough, they lacked a link to the [cc-by-sa license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) as mandated by

> 4a. You may Distribute or Publicly Perform the Work only under the terms of this License. You must include a copy of, or the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) for, this License with every copy of the Work You Distribute or Publicly Perform.

I note the website appears to have [died around 2012](http://web.archive.org/web/20120501182632/http://wwv.comanswer.com/).